# What DLL files are needed for PHP Curl (Win 10 Microsoft)

Tags: php, curl, dll

Over the last few days / week - Ive been trying to add PHP curl to my PHP - on a Win 10 Machine. however so far its not listed / showing.

i have Googled & found various places that advise of a missing DLL file & the person added the DLL & their problem was fixed :). Does anyone know a full list of the required DLL files ? I think ive added them all.

PHP Version 7.1.9

Server API  CGI/FastCGI

Loaded Configuration File   C:\WINDOWS\php.ini

extension_dir   C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.1\ext\

Here are the DLL files I have (that i remember being mentioned - in my EXT directory).

- libea32.dll
- libssh2
- php_curl.dll

(along with a few other dozen files)

is there a good page that advises everything to check for - instead of bits-and-pieces of information, so we can get curl underway ?

EDIT: i am on an WIN IIS 7 Server.

FURTHER - 19 Sep.

FURTHER: Ive checked my PHP error logs & i'm getting these errors with curl & also other DLL files (but PHP seems top be working ok).

[19-Sep-2017 07:55:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: curl: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20160303,NTS,VC14
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20160303,TS,VC14
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

What is TS / NTS ?

FURTHER EDIT: It appears im using the TS version of PHP, but i should use NTS on a Windows IIS 7 server.  Now research. (i'm guessing i need to uninstall PHP 7 get the new PHP ??)

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10, using PHP 7.1.8 extension=php_curl.dll on php.ini

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc>curl --version
curl 7.51.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.51.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2j zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.15.0 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 Metalink
```

Comment: Ah - Thanks..  i dont have any curl drivers in that directory.  is that where the php_curl.dll file goes ? i'll test it tonight when i get home...  PS - The php_curl.dll file is in my path - does that matter ?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.1\ext>curl --version
'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @G Stewpot take a look at installation openssl with curl http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/objectstorage/restrict_rw_accs_cntainers_REST_API/files/installing_curl_command_line_tool_on_windows.html

Comment: ok, gotta go - back tonight, But Im NOT on linux. im on a windows machine (we dont have sudo, or the ./config commands  etc )  I am familiar with linux but long time ago. i'll figure out the Windows equivalent..

Comment: Sorry bad link look at the link updated is the CLI for windows 10 you need openssl cos https calling in curl  ...

Comment: Ive added a excerpt from my PHP error log. (just looked). What is TS / NTS ?

Comment: added openssl - still no curl (see my php error - above)

Comment: @G Stewpot is Thread Save or No thead save, you have to show with a echo phpinfo(); page test to show wich one you have to use. and the compiler ref like : MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015)  or ...

Answer (score 0):

YES - Ive finally got CURL going :)

i was using the TS version of PHP - not the NTS version.

Ive re-installed PHP & added curl, easy as. works now on my home server :)